# Joi: Validate date to be greater than x days from now

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

Validate the date field to be greater than x days from **now**.

Right now I have this snippet that checks if the date is greater than now.

```
planned_date: Joi.date().greater('now').required()
```

But I want to validate that the `planned_date` is **at least** 2 days more than now.
This could be possible combining with `moment.js`, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Can you do something like this? 
`const dateLater = moment.tz(new Date(), '').unix() +  48 * 60 * 60`
This will give you date 2 days later at same time and then later on you can do this

`planned_date: Joi.date().greater(dateLater).required()`

Comment: @reD Here I'm just concerned that the _dateLater_ might become a hard value rather than being evaluated every time. I'll try if this works.

Comment: Also, something in-built with JOI would be better.

Comment: Ahh, actually idk if there is anything built on joi but this will definitely work.
`planned_date: Joi.date().required().greater(Date.now() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: @rED Your above comment with 'Date.now() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000' works well for me. I think you can add it as an answer as well.

Comment: Sure, will be adding it in answer as well. Happy to help :')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will check for date greater than 2 days, what we are doing is using `Date.now()` to get current time stamp in epoch later adding 2 days time in epoch to get the validation we wanted.

`planned_date: Joi.date().required().greater(Date.now() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: Is the right way to do it when validating request parameters? Because `Date.now` will be the date that the server opened(or sth like that). I was having this issue and a custom validator helped instead of this answer. Therefore, i was taking the `Date.now` in every request inside the custom validator.